# Use flatten() on a list of 2d arrays to get a list of 1d arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list `e` of 2d arrays, which I want to flatten to get a list of 1d arrays

When I use on one element:

```
e[0].flatten()
```

it works. But when I want to transform every element with:

```
enew = [e[i].flatten() for i in e]
```

the failure gets raised:

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Comment: You are indexing the array `e` using elements in `e` as indices. So when you call `e[i]` you are using an array (`i`) as an index to a list (`e`). As the error message suggests, only integer and boolean arrays are acceptable as indices for lists. What you want is to call `flatten()` on each item individually (see the answer by @YTTY).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be i.flatten() not e[i].flattent() I guess

Answer (score 0):

i is an index so it should be an int not a list, so:

```
enew = [e[i].flatten() for i in len(e)]
```